# Question about telescope eyepieces

Tags: telescope, jupiter, saturn

[image]I have a Celestron 60LCM refractor telescope. It has a 60mm aperture and a 700mm focal length. It came with two eyepieces. One is 25mm and the other is 9mm. They are marked only with their focal length - there is no brand name or part number printed or stamped on either. I can view Jupiter and Saturn through both eyepieces. However, even though the 9mm should have a higher magnification, the planets actually look smaller when looking through it than they do when viewing them through the 25mm eyepiece. Is this a field of view issue? And if so, what field of view should I look for when I shop for new eyepieces for viewing Saturn and Jupiter?

Comment: Can you post some images of these? Maybe the markings were misplaced. Sometimes we can tell the true focal length of the eyepiece just by looking at it.

Comment: I posted an image of the eyepieces.

Comment: If the planets look smaller in the 9mm than in the 25mm then it's possible that the eyepiece has as some point been disassembled and reassembled, with one of the lenses reversed.

Comment: If K is for [Kellner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyepiece#Kellner_or_%22Achromat%22), the flat lens surfaces should face outward. I doubt that reversing one would have much effect on magnification.

Comment: Actually, looking at Saturn tonight, even though it appeared smaller in the 9mm eyepiece, it had finer detail. With the 25mm, Saturn looks like a flying saucer, where the rings are attached to the planet. With the 9mm, I can see the space between the planet and the rings. So I'm not sure what is going on. I think I am going to order two new eyepieces. Any recommendations?

Comment: It could also be possible that one eyepiece has a much wider field of view than the other, misleading you into thinking the image is "smaller" because it doesn't fill the field of view as much.